# Entity Framework: Database doesn't show up in SQL Server Management Studio after "dotnet ef database update"

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am currently following some tutorials in order to learn how to use ASP.NET to create APIs:

First I used

```
dotnet ef add migrations RecipesEntity
```

in the Package Manager Console and everything was fine. Then I used

```
dotnet ef database update
```

and reading the console, it seems my migrations have been added but once I head over to the SQL Server Management Studio, I can't find the database nor the tables (I refreshed, restarted the programs, restarted my laptop)?

[Package Manager console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whfek.png)

[This is my appsettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yn6p.png)

[The Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnCCg.png)

[The DataContext class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwRKq.png)

I couldn't find anyone with this problem online. Originally my connection string was:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost\\sqlexpress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

but that was causing another error that I was trying to fix for hours so in the end when I changed it it worked for at least showing the database update logs in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably not connecting to the same instance of SQL Server in SSMS as the `dotnet ef update` is applying the changes to.

localhost and localhost\SQLEXPRESS are two different SQL Server instances (with different databases). Make sure the "Server Name" in the SSMS login screen shows only `localhost` and not `localhost\sqlexpress`

Comment: Thank you man , you dont know how nice it felt seeing it working after banging my head the whole day on this

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: in my case i had multiple dbs like local/sqlexpress0, local/sqlexpress1, local/sqlexpress2, finally found that it was actually created in local/sqlexpress02, so yeh i think it worked, thanks.